# Writing preceding zeros with ofstream

Tags: c++, io, ofstream

I am writing a program that will read and write a file format that dictates the content of the file, byte by byte. The nature of this program is that the first two bytes details how many bytes are left in that part of the file, followed by another two bytes that indicates what the part of the file actually represents. This pattern is repeated for the length of the file. This means I have to write the exact numbers buffered by preceding zeros such that each component is the exact size it needs to be. I have written up a dummy file that illustrates my points:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  std::ofstream outputFile;
  outputFile.open("test.txt", 
          std::ios::out | std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);
  const int16_t HEADER = 0x0002;
  int16_t recordSize = 2*sizeof(int16_t);
  int16_t version = 0x0258;
  outputFile << recordSize << HEADER << version;
  outputFile.close();
}
```

which writes a file named "test.txt" who's hex contents are:

```
34 32 36 30 30
```

and for those of us that can read straight hex this translates to:

```
42600
```

As you can see the preceding zeros are removed and my record is not what I was hoping it to be. Is there a way to use ofstream to buffer my numbers with zeros as I naively tried to do by using int16_t for all of the writes that I wanted to be exactly two bytes long? Is there another, possibly more stylistically correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

operator<< is for text formatting. You probably want to use .write() instead.

e.g.

```
outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&recordSize), sizeof(int16_t));
outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&HEADER), sizeof(int16_t));
// ...
```

Comment: Agreed this is what any "true" binary format would need.  Another possible concern is endianness - and `hton`/`ntoh` et al are useful support for that.  It's also vaguely possible that the file content is expect to be fixed-width text fields, in which case the OP should stick to `<<` but look at `std::setfill` and `std::setw`.

Comment: Is there an analogue I should use for reading that will give me the same guarantees? I will mark this with the "accepted answer" once I have time to test it and if tit works. Thanks!